# Import data file into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions dictionary for debugging?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

I'm exporting files as NSData objects and associating their file types with my app.

I can then import the file by opening mail on a device, then clicking the file and opening the app with it.

However, in doing that I can't launch the app from XCode to debug the file parsing.  The app is launched from mail, not XCode.

Is it possible to launch the app in XCode and have the data file end up in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions dictionary?

Comment: I think, You can refer/see  this bolg http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: That blog shows how to register for file types, not how to launch with a file under Xcode so the debugger can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to import files on both the simulator and the device in order to debug.

Note that the app must already be installed on the simulator or device for this to work, and of course the app must be set up for the data (as shown in the link in the question above).

In XCode 4 click edit scheme.

[image: click scheme]

[image: edit scheme]

Then in the info tab select "Wait for (app name) to launch."

[image: wait for launch]

Simulator:
Drag your file into the simulator window.  Safari will open and ask if you want to import it into the app.

Device:
Open your mail and select the file, it will ask if you want to open with the app.

When the app runs, the debugger will attach and you can debug as normal.